# Make a dynamic JSON based on the select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this modal view :

```html
<div class="modal fade" id ="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delta Rom insert missed entries</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Event:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="eventData" name="type" data-placeholder="Select"
                                    class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <option value="Harvest">
                                    Harvest Product Machine
                                </option>
                                <option value="Tara">
                                    Tara Machine
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id ="producttab" class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select name="harvest" id ="harvestData" data-placeholder="Select"
                                    class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($this->datamodal['products'] as $value) {
                                    echo '<option value = "' . $value->name . '">' . $value->name . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id ="tabmachines" class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Machine:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select name="machine" id ="machineData" data-placeholder="Select"
                                    class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($this->datamodal['machines'] as $value) {
                                    echo '<option value = "' . $value->name . '">' . $value->name . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>    
                            </select>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="impuritytab" class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Impurity:</label> 
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="impurities" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputimpuritiesData" 
                                   placeholder="Impurities">    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id ="humiditytab" class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Humidity:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="humidity" type="text" class="form-control" id="humidityAData" 
                                   placeholder="Humidity">
                        </div>    
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="saveModal" type="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I got 2 types of events with value Harvest or Tara, depending on the event selected I show some particular div's like this:

```
$('#eventData').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt=="Tara") {
    $("#producttab").hide();
    $("#impuritytab").hide();
    $("#humiditytab").hide();
    }else if (opt == "Harvest") {
    $("#producttab").show();
    $("#impuritytab").show();
    $("#humiditytab").show();
    }
});
```

I have a ajax that will submit that form:

```
function onAddMissedEntryInfoClicked(entryId) {
var currentEntryId = entryId;
$('#myModal').modal('show');  //this load modal view
$("#saveModal").unbind( "click");
$('#saveModal').bind('click', function(){
    var event = $('#eventData').val();
    var product = $('#harvestData').val();
    var machine = $('#machineData').val();
    var impurities = $("#inputimpuritiesData").val();
    var humidity = $("#humidityData").val();
    var dataJson = {
        "eventid":currentEntryId,
        "event": event,
        "product": product,
        "machine": machine,
        "impurities": impurities,
        "humidity":humidity

    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Monitor/thisUpdate",
        data: dataJson,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
         $('#myModal').modal('hide');

 });

 }
```

My problem is that when I'm on the Machine option, I will see only the tabmachines id field (that is good) but when I submit I will send all form values including the fields that I was hiding in my jQuery. I want to only send the forms on the select option, in my case only send machine values. How I can make my ajax data in a dynamic way? Thank you!

Comment: You could add/remove classes to the elements that are currently active and only grab those on the ajax call. You could also simply grab the elements that aren't hidden and send those along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an if clause in your onAddMissedEntryInfoClicked and create a different json object according to the event data.

```
if (event==="Harvest") {
   var dataJson = {
    "eventid":currentEntryId,
    "event": event,
    "machine": machine
   };
}
else if (event==="Tara") {
  var dataJson = {
    "eventid":currentEntryId,
    "event": event,
    "product": product
    "impurities": impurities,
    "humidity":humidity
   };
}
```